# Is there a fast way to train many models at the same time?

Tags: python, classification, text-classification, naivebayes, multiclass-classification

I want to train a 2-way classifier, that is, assume I have 4 classes that I want to classify a text to. I don't want to group all the training data in one training set and the labels then would be 4 labels. Rather, I want to make a binary labels. For example, I have to first make 4 copies of the dataset, and then, I make label A and the rest Not A, and then the second dataset would be B and Not B and so on..

After that, I have to make 4 models(naive bayes for example) and train every dataset I made. What I want is a method to do all of that without all of this work. Is that possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this strategy where separate binary classifiers are fit for each of multiple classes present in a single dataset is called "one versus all" or ["one versus rest"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiclass_classification#One-vs.-rest). Some sklearn models come with this available as a parameter, such as [logistic regression](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.LogisticRegression.html) where you can set the `multi_class` parameter to `'ovr'` for one v. rest.

There's a nice sklearn object that makes it easy for other algorithms called [OneVersusRestClassifier](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.multiclass.OneVsRestClassifier.html#sklearn.multiclass.OneVsRestClassifier). For your naive bayes example, it's as easy as:

```
from sklearn.multiclass import OneVsRestClassifier
from sklearn.naive_bayes import GaussianNB

clf = OneVsRestClassifier(GaussianNB())
```

Then you can use your classifier as normal from there, e.g. `clf.fit(X,y)`

(Interestingly, a one versus all naive bayes model is not simply equivalent to multinomial naive bayes when there are three or more classes, as I had initially assumed. There's a short example [here](http://qwone.com/~jason/writing/ova.pdf) which demonstrates this.)

Comment: I'm using a pipleline and text classification and it's giving me this error:
`A sparse matrix was passed, but dense data is required. Use X.toarray() to convert to a dense numpy array.`